# Lower bound on norm of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\vert \vert . \vert \vert$ be the 2-norm. Since this norm is submultiplicative, we know that for any two square matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,

$$ \vert \vert A B \vert \vert \leq \vert\vert A \vert \vert \vert \vert B \vert \vert \leq \sigma_{\textrm{max}}(A) \vert \vert B \vert \vert.$$

What I am looking for is an inequality of the form

$$ \sigma_{\textrm{min}}(A) \vert \vert B \vert \vert \leq \vert \vert A B \vert \vert. $$

The first inequality is true because this norm simply satisfies the submultiplicative property. But what about the second inequality? Is it true? And if not, is it only true for special type of matrices?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The inequality is true. It is obvious when $A$ is singular. When $A$ is invertible, for any unit vector $x$, we have $\|x^TA\|\ge\sigma_\min(A)$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\|AB\| &= \max_{\|x\|=1} \|x^TAB\|\\
&= \max_{\|x\|=1} \|x^TA\|\left\|\frac{x^TA}{\|x^TA\|}B\right\|\tag{1}\\
&\ge \max_{\|x\|=1} \sigma_\min(A)\left\|\frac{x^TA}{\|x^TA\|}B\right\|\\
&= \max_{\|y\|=1} \sigma_\min(A)\left\|y^TB\right\|\tag{2}\\
&= \sigma_\min(A)\|B\|,
\end{align}
where we have used the assumption that $A$ is invertible in $(1)$ (so that we can divide by $\|x^TA\|\neq0$) and $(2)$ (so that every $x$ corresponds to a unique $y$ and vice versa).

Comment: Hi -- I was wondering if you may be able to take a look at a related question here and provide any https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383675/on-inequalities-for-norms-of-matrices insights? Also, if you may be able to look at the third question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382895/on-the-polynomial-formula-for-determinants then it would be much appreciated. Pls let me know. thank you!

Comment: @user1551 just brilliant!!!

Answer (score 13):

By use of the multiplicativity of the spectral norm: 
$$\|ABB^{-1}\|_2 \le \|AB\|_2\|B^{-1}\|_2,$$
which implies that
$$\|AB\|_2\ge \|A\|_2 \frac{1}{\|B^{-1}\|_2}.$$