# matrix operator 2 norm inequality involving product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, is it true that
$$
\| BAB^T \|_2 \geq C \| B\|^2_2\| A\|_2
$$
for some constant $C$? Assuming all matrices are real and the constant may depend on the size $n$.

Here $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is the induced/operator 2-norm defined as

$\| A \|_2 = \sup \limits _{x \ne 0} \frac{\| A x\| _2}{\|x\|_2}$

Comment: Is $B$ just any matrix?

Comment: Yes, B is any matrix

Comment: In general you should have $$ \|AB \| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$$ and $\|A^T\| = \|A \|$. If $A$ is positive definite then $\|A\|_{2} = \lambda_{\text{max}}(A)$. I'm not sure about the constant. You can have $\|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt{r} \|A\|_2$ where $r$ is the rank of the matrix. It's full rank so it's $n$

Comment: In fact, I need some inequality of the other direction, for example, since $A$ is positive definite, I can let $D = \sqrt{A}$, and $BAB^T = BD (BD)^T$, then I have $\| BD (BD)^T\|_2= \| BD\|^2_2$. Now maybe there is a constant that $\|BD \|_2 \geq C\| B\|_2\|D\|_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can find a constant that is dependent on $A$ alone.

Based on your comment you can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|BAB^T\|_2 &= \|(BA^{1/2}) (B A^{1/2})^T\|_2 \\
&= \|BA^{1/2}\|^2_2 \\
&\geq \|B\|_2^2 \sigma_{\min}(A^{1/2})^2 \\
& = \|B\|_2^2 \sigma_{\min}(A)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where on the second line we used the fact that $\|XX^*\|_2 = \|X\|_2^2$ (transposition gives the adjoint operator if we view the vector space as a real inner product space and note that the $2$-norm of the vector can be defined via this inner product). On the third line we used the inequality found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268316/lower-bound-on-norm-of-product-of-two-matrices). Noting that $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_{\max}(A)$ we can take $C = \frac{\sigma_{\min}(A)}{\sigma_{\max}(A)}$ which is non-trivial as $A$ is positive definite.